# How can I display the number of clicks for each item of a state separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

As of now, upon clicking on any of the 4 food types, they appear on the modal with no problems.

Here's the problem:

Whenever I click on any button for the first time, a `0` is displayed.  Whenever I click on any button again (besides the one I clicked previously) for the second time, a `1` is displayed.

Whenever I click on any button again (besides the one I clicked previously) for the third time, a `2` is displayed.  Whenever I click on any button again (besides the one I clicked previously) a `3` appears.

I want to display the number of times a button is clicked separately.  For example, if I clicked `Chicken Taco` 4 times and I clicked `Beef Taco` 2 times, then `2` and `4` should appear in the modal.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import FoodButton from '../FoodButtons/FoodButton';
import CheckoutButton from '../CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';
import axios from '../../../../axios-foodChosen';

import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedItems: [],

            foodClicks: {
                cTacoClicked: 0,
                bTacoClicked: 0,
                cBurritoClicked: 0,
                bBurritoClicked: 0,
            }

        };

        //Constant item names
        this.items = {
            chickenTaco: 'Chicken Taco',
            beefTaco: 'Beef Taco',
            chickenBurrito: 'Chicken Burrito',
            beefBurrito: 'Beef Burrito'
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // for modal
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    selectFood(food) {
        this.setState(state => {
            let selected = state.selectedItems;
            let cTaco = state.foodClicks.cTacoClicked;
            let bTaco = state.foodClicks.bTacoClicked;
            let cBurrito = state.foodClicks.cBurritoClicked;
            let bBurrito = state.foodClicks.bBurritoClicked;

            if(!selected.includes(food)) {
                selected.push(food);
            }

            return {
                selectedItems: selected,
                cTacoClicked: cTaco + 1,
                bTacoClicked: bTaco + 1,
                cBurritoClicked: cBurrito + 1,
                bBurritoClicked: bBurrito + 1
            };
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                {Object.keys(this.items).map(key => (
                    <FoodButton clicked={() => this.selectFood(key)} key={key} label={this.items[key]}/>
                ))}

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>

                    {this.state.selectedItems.map(key => (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <p key={key}>{this.items[key]}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))}

                    {Object.keys(this.state.selectedItems.map(key => (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <p key={key}>{this.state.foodClicks[key]}</p><br/>
                        </div>
                    )))}

                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // props for modal
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TacoTypes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cTacoClicked: cTaco + 1,
bTacoClicked: bTaco + 1,
cBurritoClicked: cBurrito + 1,
bBurritoClicked: bBurrito + 1
```

Currently, you are adding 1 to all food click counters. Instead, you should only increment the counter of the selected food.

In `constructor()`, use the item keys as the click counters keys to make things easy. Initialize state like this:

```
    this.state = {
        selectedItems: [],

        foodClicks: {
            chickenTaco: 0,
            beefTaco: 0,
            chickenBurrito: 0,
            beefBurrito: 0,
        }
    };
```

And this is implementation of `selectFood()`:

```
selectFood(food) {
    this.setState(state => {
        let selected = state.selectedItems;

        if(!selected.includes(food)) {
            selected.push(food);
        }

        return {
            selectedItems: selected,
            foodClicks: {
                ...state.foodClicks,
                [food]: state.foodClicks[food] + 1
            }
        };
    });
}
```